# SQL Query to count two different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a below table where I want an output of total ID and "Total Trade Role" per "Branch".
For example for the branch Kent we have a count of 3 "Trade ID" and "Total Trade Role"= 5 because TradeID 12232 holds 2 member ID and TradeID 6556 holds 1 Member ID.

Any help on how can I count total member ID and Total Trade role against each Branch?

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I dont get how Total Trade Role equals 5, because in your explanation you make it sound like it should be 3.

Comment: Total Trade Role  = 5 because each  trade role is associated with Trade ID and Trade ID is unique. So, for Trade ID  12232 Total trade role is only 2 and for Trade ID 6556 is 3 so 3+2=5

Comment: @Shmiel I did this Select t1.Branch,Count (t1.ID) as Total ID, count(t1.TotalTraderole)

From table t1

group by t1.branch ,t1.tradeID,t1.totaltraderole      but doesn't work

Comment: *`group by t1.branch ,t1.tradeID,t1.totaltraderole`* Why do you `group by t1.tradeID, t1.totaltraderole` if those columns are in `count()`?

Comment: And [edit] your question and add what you tried, and what it returns, and what the desired results should be. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Shmiel I'm new in sql, could you help with this or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
    select
      branch,
      id,
      TradeID,
      TotalTradeRole,
      DENSE_RANK() over (partition by branch order by tradeid) as denbrach
    from #traderole
),
sum_brach as
(
    select
      branch,
      sum(totaltraderole) over (partition by denbrach, branch order by totaltraderole) as totaltraderole
    from cte 
    group by
      branch,
      denbrach,
      totaltraderole 
),
got_sum as
(
    select
      branch,
      sum(totaltraderole) as totaltraderole
    from sum_brach
    group by
      branch
),
total_tradeid as
(
    select
      branch,
      count(tradeid) as totalid
    from #traderole
    group by
      Branch
)
select
  g.branch as Branch,
  tt.totalid as [Total ID],
  g.totaltraderole as [Total Trade Role]
from got_sum g
inner join total_tradeid tt on g.branch = tt.branch
```

Comment: I am not sure how to format my answer. Are you looking (Brighton, TotalID=3,Total TradeRole=7)   (Kent,Total ID=2, Total Trade Role=5) (London,TotalID=2, Total Trade Role=4) ?

Comment: Thank you brother, I'm looking for Brighton totalID = 4 , Total TradeRole=7 yes, Kent total ID = 3 as all the ID is unique , and total trade role =5 , and London totalID=2 and yes, Total trade role =4

Comment: I understand, one moment, will fix this now.

Comment: upvote if so, if its not the right answer just let me know.

Comment: Also I edited the original post to the correct.

Comment: Thank you brother, I will try it and let you know, definitely upvote it.

Comment: No problem, it will give the correct out put, Be sure to change the #traderole table to whatever your table name is.

Comment: You might have to format it correctly. Let me know if you do. Usually someone might format the answer on this page in a bit, we will see

Comment: Thank you , I will let you know once I get your script implemented.

Comment: Do us all a favour and format it properly. Some explanation of the code wouldn't go amiss

Comment: I have no idea how to format, I started yesterday.

Comment: Most of what I did was formatting the actual SQL with whitespace and newlines, that you can do yourself. To create a code block you put three backticks before and after ``` See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).